# Smarty var unexpected 1

Tags: php, variables, smarty

I have the following code and the output.

If i print_r, normal echo {} of foreach, i am getting the number 1?

What do i do wrong?!

Controller:

```
if( $checkOrderNumber == '' || $checkOrderNumber == NULL ){
    $var = '<a class="tool-link" href="url.php?dispatch=orders.details&order_id='. $_REQUEST['order_id'] .'&sendsurvey=yes">Send FBC invitation</a>';
}else{
    $var = '<a href="#">FBC has been sent</a>';
}

Registry::get('view')->assign('var', $var);
```

Smarty TPL:

```
        {assign var="var" value=$var}
        <li>{$var}</li>
```

or

```
        {foreach from=$feedbackcompany item=foo}
            <li>{$foo}</li>
        {/foreach}
```

Output:

```
<li><a class="tool-link" href="admin.php?dispatch=orders.details&amp;order_id=238205&amp;sendsurvey=yes">Send FBC invitation</a>1</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show me what it returns ?

```
var_dump($smarty->getTemplateVars())
```

before Registry::get('view')->assign('var', $var);

And you don't must use {assign var="var" value=$var}. TPL allready has it

Comment: i am getting this error. Notice: Undefined variable: smarty in /home/url/html/update/app/controllers/backend/orders.php on line 314 Fatal error: Call to a member function getTemplateVars() on a non-object in /home/site/html/update/app/controllers/backend/orders.php on line 314 $var was an example ;-)

Comment: try `var_dump(Registry::get('view')->getTemplateVars())` instead

Comment: @Bas The main task for this moment -- detect place where "1" is added.